# How hard is it to get a research oriented job in the US with an Austrailian PhD (Computer Engineering)?

Tags: phd, united-states, postdocs, australia

How hard is it to get a job at a leading research lab in the US (like Amazon, Microsoft) with an Australian PhD (from University of New South Wales, Sydney)?

Will taking up a postdoc position in a US university help?
If not, what is the best route I can take?

Comment: I doubt that it is easier than anywhere else. Pretty hard since your pool is small. The degree isn't the problem. The competition is.

Comment: Suppose I have good credentials, i.e., good publications etc.?

Comment: Helpful, of course. Good luck.

Comment: If you have the legal right to work in the US, a degree from an Australian university is just as good as one from an American university.  For most people with Australian PhDs, the real Australia-specific problem will be getting a work visa.

Comment: As usual, very much depends on the area.  One of our students got hired immediately by a large research lab once he/she graduated.

Comment: Also the quality of your publications will weigh more heavily than where you got your PhD.

Comment: The difficulty is about 6.79. Hope that helps!

Comment: The 'best' route would be getting a job (post-doc or otherwise) with Microsoft or Amazon or Google or another company you want to work for. The second best is to get a good job you like doing (well, actually this is first best period).